# When i retrieve data from mongoDB it works but when i send it to client via NodeJS it returns an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, frontend, backend

//error
/*
ReferenceError: opinion is not defined
10:53:28 web.1   |      at Object.getOpinionByIDCode (/Users/ochetta/Desktop/explainfreely/app/database.js:54:3)
10:53:28 web.1   |      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
*/

```
//nodeJS backend code
app.get('/getOpinion', function (req, res) {
    const opinionCode = req.query.IDcode
    console.log(opinionCode)
    databaseManager.getOpinionByIDCode(opinionCode).then(requestedOpinion => {
        res.json(requestedOpinion)
    })
})


//vanilla javascript frontend code
postRes = document.getElementById('postRes')
function showPost() {
    const opinionCode = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('IDcode')
    const requestOpinionURL = '/getOpinion?IDcode=' + opinionCode
    fetch(requestOpinionURL)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(post => {
            postRes.innerText = post.title
        })
}
window.onload = function() {
    showPost()
}


//database backend code
async function getOpinionByIDCode(opinionIDCode) {
    try {
        await client.connect()
        database = client.db("HerokuWebsite")
        categories = ['design', 'drugs', 'internet', 'jokes', 'literature', 'music', 'other', 'politics', 'sexuality', 'sport']
        for (category of categories) {
            collection = database.collection(category)
            await collection.findOne({opinionNumber: opinionIDCode})
                .then(post => {
                    if (post != null) {
                        opinion = post
                    }
                })
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. My problem was that i was passing a string to the function and not a number so when i searched the opinionNumber I passed a string and there were only numbers in there